# How to get Hidden Partitions in the Harddisk in VC++?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, systems-programming, disk-partitioning

How to get Hidden Partitions in the Harddisk in VC++?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542456%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
This msdn code is giving the list of all available drives in local PC. Thanks.